# Nav Host Fragment Duplicate id

Tags: mvvm, fragment, navigation-drawer, android-databinding

I already found a solution to this. But it took quite a while and a lot of references to stumble upon so I will leave this here.

This is an app that has **MVVM data binding throwing error related to Nav Controller**.

fragment initially gave **Duplicate id error on NavHostFrament** on the data binding line in my activity. Removing either android:id or android:name gave either build error or runtime error.

Activity.kt

```
     binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home)
     .
     .
     .
     val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

Layout.xml

```
  <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>
```

while the fragment line gave me a lint check to convert to FragmentContainerView it started throwing **NavController not set** error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I transferred the fragment tag to a separate xml file. Though I believe this is not needed.

nav_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

As for the **Activity** file.
Following this link...  **https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973#comment4**

Replaced

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

with

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Comment: And how do you change the fragments? I do not get any error but also don't see any content either

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem then I realized that I set the content view of the activitiy both using setContentView() method and DataBindingUtil.setContentView() method. I removed one of them and the problem is solved.

I replaced my code from:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

to:

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```